# Extracting value from Option with match gives "unable to infer enough type information..." error

Tags: rust

I'm trying simply to convert an inputted string into an integer. I know this can be done by applying `unwrap` to `from_str` but I figured I'd try to handle the error case properly and extract the value with a match instead. Instead of it working as expected I just get this error...

> error: unable to infer enough type information about `_`; type annotations required`which points to the`x`in`Some(x)`

```
fn main () {
    let ref num = os::args()[1];
    match from_str(num.as_slice()) {
        Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        None => println!("string cannot be converted to int"),
    }
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s look at [the definition of `from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_str.html):

```
pub fn from_str<A: FromStr>(s: &str) -> Option<A>
```

The return type, you see, may be an `Option` of any type that implements [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html), such as `int`, `u8` and `IpAddr`. If you don’t say explicitly what `A` is, by changing `from_str(…)` to `from_str::<int>(…)` or similar, the compiler will try to figure out what it can be. In this case, it will look forward and see that `x` is of type `A` and based on the usage of `x`, it must implement [`std::fmt::Show`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fmt/trait.Show.html) as well. There is nothing else that it can infer.

Well then, what types implement both `FromStr` and `Show`? There are quite a few of them, and as soon as there’s more than one it is impossible for the compiler to decide what you meant, so it gives up.

The solution is to stipulate what type you are wishing to parse that argument as, by writing `from_str::<int>(num.as_slice())` or similar.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough explanation!

Answer (score 2):

The return type of [`from_str`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/fn.from_str.html) is generic. It can return any type that implements [`FromStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/trait.FromStr.html), wrapped in an `Option`. The compiler could not infer what type you want from the value's usage, because `println!` is also generic. Is it `i32`, `f64`, `bool`, something else?

You can specify the type you want on the `from_str` call:

```
fn main() {
    let ref num = os::args()[1];
    match from_str::<i32>(num.as_slice()) {
        Some(x) => println!("{}", x),
        None => println!("string cannot be converted to int"),
    }
}
```